# ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error) for cross-origin fetch request

Tags: aurelia

In my app when I save data using a webAPI hosted in IIS with this code

```
postHistoricoCertificaciones(data: CertifiedPlanningData) {
return this.http
  .fetch(`planning/PostHistoricoCertificaciones`, {
    method: "post",
    body: json(data)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(savedPlanning => {
    console.log(
      "Planificación Histórica de Certificaciones guardada correctamente"
    );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(
      "Se ha producido un error guardando la planificación Histórica de Certificaciones"
    );
  });
```

}
All works fine but when I try to print data with this similar code and using the same webAPI

```
Print(printData: PrintData) {
return this.http
  .fetch(`planning`, {
    method: "post",
    body: json(printData)
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(savedPlanning => {
    console.log(
      "Planificación de Subcontrataciones guardada correctamente"
    );
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(
      "Se ha producido un error guardando la planificación de Subcontrataciones"
    );
  });
```

}

I get this error
POST http://planificadorwebapi.fyseg.com:8070/api/planning net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
:5000/#/proyectos/X0000143/empleado/40/plan/horas:1 Access to fetch at 'http://planificadorwebapi.fyseg.com:8070/api/planning' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any idea, please?

regards

Comment: I use a similar approach as well as almost the same backend. You enabled CORS on your server. I'd check if the second api route `planning` is throwing an exception. If so, at the client level you get a CORS message, but on the server you got an internal server error due to a serialization error, an unchecked null, etc.

Comment: The ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error) problem is the problem you need to solve. Check your server logs in the `http://planificadorwebapi.fyseg.com:8070/api/planning` server environment and see what messages the server is logging before it fails and sends back that 500 error.